# Building the back-end server for an iPhone App

Tags: ios, web-services

I'm looking at building a simple login-based iOS application that needs secure access to create, read, updated and delete data from a MySQL database - with certain actions available to specific users based on roles.

I've done some research and it looks like I need to build a RESTful Web service which provides Web Services which the iPhone app calls to access the data.

I have very little experience of web services development, are there any books/tutorials that are worth checking out? Is it worth looking at a web framework, rather than start from sractch?

I've done some basic web development in PHP/Python so would prefer to build in that I think..given that hosting it would be relatively cheap..

Have done some basic C#/Java; would it be worth looking at these instead? I tried creating a simple ASMX webservice but most of the examples cite using a MSSQL server, not sure if that is the way to go though.

Comment: This is a very subjective question - my opinion: use PHP and transfer that data using JSON. Do everything yourself as it will be really lightweight and hardly worth any framework (which would also take some time to get used to). Using JSON will allow you to easily add other platforms on the mobile side (e.g. android) as JSON parsing is very widespread and available on virtually all platforms.

Comment: @Till Yep, that was my initial reaction too. IMO it depends on the complexity/availability of the application. If it's just a playground-like thing for personal use, then JSON is definitely a quicker option to get up and running.

Comment: Thanks, if do decide that I need something a bit more complex what would be a good frameworks to start looking at? I'm looking at drupal at the minute and will take a look at django as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a framework. No point reinventing the wheel and giving yourself a headache. A good PHP based solution would be to use [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) to build the backend using the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) to provide data via webservices. Drupal is so flexible and so popular now, that you can get a lot of what you want done without any code at all.

Roughly:

1. Install Drupal 7 on a webserver according to the [instructions](http://drupal.org/documentation/install)
2. Install the Services module
3. Design the [entities](http://www.istos.it/comment/2870) that will make up your MySQL database
4. Tell the services module how you want to expose things

Some examples of API calls are [here](https://gist.github.com/affc9864487bb1b9c918).

A case study of someone else who has used Drupal as the backend for iPhone/Android is [here](http://drupal.org/node/659772).

You will have a learning curve to get your head round Drupal, but you'll have one anyway to get your head around webservices and the benefits you gain from having everything else Drupal offers are enormous, e.g.

- The difficult bits are already done for you, so the amount of code will be massively reduced, if you even need any at all
- Using Drupal's hugely flexible entities system, you can design a flexible and extensible mysql database scheme using the web based UI, which will be ready to work with any of Drupal's other modules, so you can expand add features with minimal effort in the future
- There's an enormous community of people who can help you and the forums on drupal.org are very active
- You would have a great UI for users, in case you ever need to give them access to their data through a normal website interface. Drupal has loads of pre-built themes (I recommend [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega)) which look awesome and again, little to no code is needed to get a whole site ready made along with HTML5, standards compliance etc.
- Drupal provides you with ready-made modules to provide access control via roles, as well as everything else you can imagine e.g. managing a mailing list for your users, providing you with usage statistics, admin interface for user and role management etc.
- Drupal use is exploding globally and there's a serious skills shortage, so you'd be even more employable :)

Comment: Thanks - I have been thinking about  Drupal and about using it as a platform so I will defiantly take a look at this..

I guess the user authentication will be built into this already?

Comment: Yeah, all that's done already. Creating a user in Drupal automatically means that they can then log in via webservices (once Services module is installed) and do the same stuff they can do on the front end e.g. list content, save content.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not compulsory that you use a REST web service. It's just that WS si more or less standard for web-based applications.

I'm not really familiar with PHP, but in python you have [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home). On the IOS side you have [restkit](http://restkit.org/) to pair the server with.

What I could say from my experience is that writing a prototype in django is quite easy and you can definitely use this to develop your app.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at Django - I've never really used Django before but have heard it is pretty good at these sort of things..